# Multithreading with pooling and sequential processing

Tags: java, multithreading, jpa

I'm coding in Java 8 and have data which I retrieve via HTTP-requests for further processing with JPA. My idea to multithread the processing fails cause JPA (EclipseLink) requires a sequential processing. The HTTP-request with REST-Templates is retrieved with something like `content=response.getBody().getDataChunk()` Retrieving a single HTTP-request takes about 50-70ms, but querying about 1.000s of requests takes a lot of time ==>

1. Start the HTTP-querying multithreaded
2. Save the query - most likely in a stack
3. Retrieve a single data-element from the stack and process it

But I have no clue about How to code the details. Namely in what kind of object should I use as the stack? How to initiate the ongoing processing of step 3? `Thread.join()`? Plus how to limit the amount of multiple threads to e.g. 2 or 3? `ExecutorService.newCachedPool(3)` (or something similar?) Hmmm...

How to do it correctly? Any links for this specific pattern?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  We are a question-and-answer site, not a coders-for-hire service. Please explain what you have tried so far and why it hasn't worked.  See: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: I'm not really clear what you mean with your post. Is this a standard one or does this already apply to my q? If so, than I'm curious what you wanna see. I have only a sequential code but don't know how to encapsulate them into a multi threaded code. Plus I'm curious in the design pattern...

Comment: I put this on your question because I felt it was relevant.  Please read the link, as I think it will clarify what needs to be clarified.

Answer (score 0):

I recently used code similar to the following to achieve this. I'm sure you can adapt it to work for you.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool()
List<MyType> results = urls.stream().map((String url)->executor.submit(()-> {

        return url.substring(2); // retrieve the page and do something with it

    }))
    .collect(Collectors.toList()) // this makes sure all urls are submitted before processing the results
    .stream().map(future -> {
        try {
             return future.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "failed"; // or some other value indicating failure
        }
     }).collect(Collectors.toList();
```

This works by first creating an executor service, to run multiple threads in parallel. It then takes the list of URLs and submits each of them to the `executor` to be processed in the top lambda.

After this, it collects all the results and converts them from `Future` objects to their actual values within the bottom lambda.

Comment: As far as I understand you're submitting the requests by `Executor` - all in parallel and than map the `future` by the final `.collect(Collectors.toList())`  into the results. Does this mean that I can than finally iterate over the results with a simple `.foreach(...)`? Cause the list is filled with the `future.get()` But does the `.foreach(..)` not run into some Excpetions like modifications while iterating?

Comment: @LeO I'm not sure what you're asking. Note that I edited my answer - see the comment after the first collect. This first collect gives you a `List` of your `Future`s. You can then `.foreach` over them, or use the rest of my code to convert them into a `List` of the actual result values.